# I can't assign a parent to a child in Google App Engine's Datastore. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: google-app-engine

In the code below, I'm inserting one piece of data, and then a second one assigning the first as the parent.  Both pieces of data go in, but no parent relationship is created.  What am I doing wrong?

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Test_Model(db.Model):
  """Just a model for testing."""
  name = db.StringProperty()

# Create parent data
test_data_1 = Test_Model()
test_data_1.name = "Test Data 1"
put_result_1 = test_data_1.put()

# Create child data
test_data_2 = Test_Model()
test_data_2.name = "Test Data 2"
# Here's where I assign the parent to the child
test_data_2.parent = put_result_1
put_result = test_data_2.put()

query = Test_Model.all()

results = query.fetch(100)
for result in results:
  print "Name: " + result.name
  print result.parent()
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize my misunderstanding now.  You have to set the parent at the time of creation like so:

```
test_data_2 = Test_Model(parent = put_result_1)
```

Here's the full fixed code sample for posterity.

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Test_Model(db.Model):
  """Just a model for testing."""
  name = db.StringProperty()

# Create parent data
test_data_1 = Test_Model()
test_data_1.name = "Test Data 1"
put_result_1 = test_data_1.put()

# Create child data
test_data_2 = Test_Model(parent = put_result_1)
test_data_2.name = "Test Data 2"
put_result = test_data_2.put()

query = Test_Model.all()

#query.filter('name =', 'Test Data 1')
#query.ancestor(entity)

results = query.fetch(1000)
for result in results:
  print "Name: " + result.name
  print result.parent()
```

Comment: I'd say this is a bug: If GAE ignores changes to `parent`, how do you move children in the tree?

Comment: I believe you need to copy, delete and add again.  There is no move that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Where in your model do you define the field `parent`? You define only `name`.

Therefore GAE ignores the unknown `parent` field.

Comment: I was trying to set the structural parent, not simply a property.  I figured it out though and posted the solution.